# How to create database stored procedure call that will send as one parameter table and get as one return (out) parameter table

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

How to create a database stored procedure call that will send a table as one parameter and get as one return (out) parameter table.

I start with sending table as a parameter and do something like this:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "testProcedure",
        procedureName = "testProcedure",
        resultClasses = {Integer.class},
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        mode = ParameterMode.IN,
                        name = "tabela",
                        type = Tabela.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(
                        mode = ParameterMode.OUT,
                        name = "ilosc",
                        type = Integer.class)
        }
)

public class TestProcedure implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

Also try something like this:

```
    final StoredProcedureQuery testProcedure = entityManager
            .createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("testProcedure")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(0, Object.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Object.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    List<Tabela> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(Tabela.builder().firstName("Dominik").age(11).build());
    arrayList.add(Tabela.builder().firstName("Dominik22").age(22).build());

    testProcedure.setParameter(1, arrayList);

    testProcedure.execute();
```

But everytime I get "Type cannot be null"

I make this table entity but it did not work:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tabela")
public class Tabela {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to insert to an input table (possibly a global temporary table) and then just execute the stored procedure, which could read from that table and write to a different output table (again, possibly a global temporary table) where you could then query the output.

Comment: I can not do this. I can only execute procedure on that database and that's all.